# Column does not exist, pgAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

```
INSERT INTO public."LeadCustomer"(
    "CustomerID", "FirstName", "Surname", "BillingAddress", "Email")
    VALUES ("12", "Lola", "Smith", "24 Cashmere Lane, Lancashire, LA4 6QT", "lolasmith@gmail.com");

ERROR:  column "12" does not exist
LINE 3:  VALUES ("12", "Lola", "Smith", "24 Cashmere Lane, Lancashir...
                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "12" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 111
```

Comment: use single quotes arround strings

Comment: Such a silly mistake! Thank you

Answer (score 20):

You're getting this error because PostgreSQL uses double quotes (`"`) to signify system identifiers (such as tables, columns, etc.) while using single quotes (`'`) to signify text.

You want your query to be:

```
INSERT INTO public."LeadCustomer"(
    "CustomerID", "FirstName", "Surname", "BillingAddress", "Email")
    VALUES ('12', 'Lola', 'Smith', '24 Cashmere Lane, Lancashire, LA4 6QT', 'lolasmith@gmail.com');
```